# Swift CoreAnimation: zPosition should be within (-FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX) range

Tags: swift, max, zposition

I want to keep a view always at the front. In Swift `CGFLOAT_MAX` and `FLT_MAX` are replaced with corresponding `.greatestFiniteMagnitude`. So, I used:

```
view.layer.zPosition = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
```

It works fine, but now I get a warning:

```
CoreAnimation: zPosition should be within (-FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX) range.
```

Is there a way to get rid of the warning (maybe a better value to use here)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On a 64-bit platform

```
CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude = Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude = 1.79769313486232e+308
Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude = 3.40282e+38
```

Apparently the `zPosition` should be in the (smaller) range of a `Float`:

```
view.layer.zPosition = CGFloat(Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
```

Comment: why not using `CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude` instead of casting to `CGFloat` is there a problem with that

Comment: @zombie: That are different values. On a 64-bit platform, CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude =  Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude = 1.79769313486232e+308, but Float.greatestFiniteMagnitude = 3.40282e+38.